# android list view clickable problem

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem, android-listview

i have this customized list. each row contains an image and two lines of text one below the other. i want to open a new activity when any list item is clicked. but i am not able to do so, even after implementing the setOnItemClickListener(). please correct me if i am wrong. the below is the code for the list. 
PS: This is an normal activity and not list activity.

```
l1.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this,eventTitleArray,eventDateArray,eventImageLinkArray));
   //l1 = getListView();
   l1.setClickable(true);
   l1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
      int position, long arg3) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayActivity.class);
     Bundle b = new Bundle();
     b.putString("event", eventTitleArray[position]);
     intent.putExtras(bundle);
     startActivity(intent);

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Opening detailed view for:"+eventTitleArray[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
   });
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please have a look whether the row layout has any items which are focusable. If an ListView Item contains focusable children, the Listview Handler will not be fired.

Comment: I tried doing this , holder.firstLine.setFocusable(false);
    holder.secondLine.setFocusable(false);
    holder.imageView.setFocusable(false); but it still doesn't work. firstLine,secondLine and imageView are present in each row layout.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a bug in the SDK that prevents the onItemClickListeners from firing when there are focusable views in the View of your items.

So you should try to do a setFocusable(false) on all the Views of your items.

The problem is described [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414&can=1&q=listview&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)