# List item with CheckBox not clickable

Tags: android, listview

I have a list item which contains a CheckBox, and I want to be able to click on the CheckBox and on the list item itself. Unfortunately, there seems to be some sort of conflict between the two, as I can only click on the item when I comment out the CheckBox. It seems like I recall there was a way to fix this, but I can't find it at the moment. Thanks

**EDIT:** This is with a ListFragment, so there's no need to call setOnItemClickListener.

OK, here's the XML for the list item. The problem is the CheckBox, but I figured might as well copy everything.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_survey"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/SimpleListItem">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/survey_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/ListItemTitle" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/survey_date"
        android:layout_below="@id/survey_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/ListItemSubtitle" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/survey_completed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/survey_title"
        android:textColor="@color/accent_1"
        android:text="@string/survey_completed"
        style="@style/ListItemSubtitle" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/survey_did_not_attend"
        android:layout_below="@id/survey_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/survey_did_not_attend"
        android:focusable="false"
        style="@style/ListItemSubtitle" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show us the code that you are trying.

Comment: @Shawan Lauzon : Please Specify your main List code to hear that can help to understand the your problem.

Comment: Hmm, looks like it's either a bug or works as designed: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414&can=1&q=listview&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316600/android-list-view-clickable-problem) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414&can=1&q=listview&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars), this is either a known problem or works as designed. If you have any clickable or focusable items in a list item, the list item itself cannot be clickable. Romain Guy [says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316600/android-list-view-clickable-problem) "This is working as intended to support trackball/dpad navigation."

Answer (score 28):

You need to add this to your custom adapter xml file **android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"**

Comment: adapter xml file is kind of confusing, it's the item xml file

Answer (score 23):

insert this into the ***root element of the item row*** xml file

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Comment: Worked for me .. added in root element

Answer (score 6):

This did the work for me

```
<CheckBox
...                
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
```

Comment: android:clickable="false" was the only thing that worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem this way. I implemented OnClickListener inside the Adapter and not in the Fragment/Activity and it works well. Now I can use ListView with checkboxes and can click on both. Here is my code:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
{
    ...

    private void setView()
    {
        ListView listView = (ListView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        mItems = DatabaseManager.getManager().getItems();

        // create adapter
        if(listView.getAdapter()==null)
        {
            MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, mItems);
            try
            {
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            try
            {
                ((MyAdapter) listView.getAdapter()).refill(mItems);
                BaseAdapter adapter = (BaseAdapter) listView.getAdapter();
                listView.requestLayout();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
        }

        // handle listview item click
        listView.setClickable(true);
        // listView.setOnItemClickListener(...); // this method does not work in our case, so we can handle that in adapter
    }

    ...
}


public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    ...

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mFragment.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
        }

        ...

        // handle listview item click
        // this method works pretty well also with checkboxes
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // do something here
                // for communication with Fragment/Activity, you can use your own listener
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

?

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

by using 
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
its working fine

Answer (score 0):

ok.. Make a CheckBox instance Like

```
CheckBox check;
check = (CheckBox) myView.findViewById(R.id.check);
check.setOnClickListener(new CheckBoxSelect(position));
```

put above code in `onItemClickListener` or in `Adapter` you are using. now make a class like 
below

```
private class CheckBoxSelect implements OnClickListener 
    {
        int pos;
        String str;

        public CheckBoxSelect(int position) 
        {
            pos = position;
        }

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

        }

    }
```

perform any functionality in `onClick` .

Comment: The problem is not with the checkbox. The problem is the item in the ListView not being clickable.

Comment: have you used `listView.setClickable(true)`. if not please put that before `onItemClickListener`

Comment: This is a ListFragment, so the embedded ListView is automatically clickable. See the answer above -- it's an issue in the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Late, but nevertheless a solution for all those who still need it.

It is true that the built-in mechanism using:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    getActivity(),
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, lst);
```

does not allow both, ie click on the checkbox AND click on the list item. Wherever one clicks, the checkbox catches the event.

However, if you  create your own ArrayAdapter with `getView` like this, then it works fine:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_ecu_fehler, null);
    }

    v.setFocusable(true);
    v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        if (DEBUG)
            Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                " ->>"
                    + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2]
                        .getMethodName());
        }
    });

            CheckBox selectedForClearingCB = (CheckBox) v
            .findViewById(R.id.checkBox);


        if (selectedForClearingCB != null) {
        selectedForClearingCB.setTag(position); //so we know position in the list       selectedForClearingCB.setChecked(true);
        selectedForClearingCB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                if (DEBUG)
                Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                    " -> CB checked: "
                        + Integer.toString((Integer) v
                            .getTag()));

            }

            }
        });
        }
    }
    return v;
    }

}
```