# Listitem click doesn't work with checkboxes Android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

**EDIT (SOLVED)** For the answer go to the bottom of the question.

I have a listview and I inflate some rows in it using a customadapter.
The row being inflated contains a checkbox. I can maintain the checkbox's status, but the problem is, my list items are no more clickable.
Here's my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    fl=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.MainMenu);//Mainmenu is listview
    fl.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(Annotate.this,R.layout.preann2,_dir));//preann2 is row and _dir is the list of objects
    //fl.setOnItemClickListener(this); tried this too
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View view, int pos, long id) 
{
      //Implementations
}

    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId,objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.preann2, parent, false);
            try
            {

            TextView Name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.title);
            Name.setText("xyz");
            ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            row.setFocusable(true);
            row.setClickable(true);
            row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    checkState[position]=!checkState[position];
                }

            });
            CheckBox c=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            c.setChecked(checkState[position]);
            c.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton v,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    CheckBox checkBox=(CheckBox)v;
                    if (isChecked) {
                        checkState[position]=true;
                     }
                    else
                        checkState[position]=false;
                }
            });
            /*  tried this too
                                  c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox checkBox=(CheckBox)v;
                    if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                        //checkBox.setChecked(false);
                        checkState[position]=true;
                     }
                    else
                        checkState[position]=false;
                }});*/
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }catch(Throwable err)
            {
                err.printStackTrace();
            }
            return row;
        }
}
```

I want the listitems to be clickable in case the user wants to click only a single item.

**EDIT (on Akhil's request)-**
preann2.xml in layouts folder:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:padding="4dip"
  >

 <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_marginRight="4dip"/>


  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/title"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:ellipsize="end"
  android:gravity="center_vertical"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:textStyle="bold" />

<CheckBox
  android:id="@+id/checkBox"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

main.xml in layouts folder:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/MainMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT (SOLVED)**
Just add these properties to checkbox:

```
  android:focusable="false"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: If you want the checkBox to be checked if the row is clicked, then put the conditions with the `onClickListener()` for the row itself.

Comment: I want some other actions to do when i click the items in the listview. Checkboxes i can set directly by clicking on them, so problems about that.
I actually want to call an activity when i click an item.

Comment: Try adding a `log` inside the `onClickListener` for the checkbox and let us know if the log is registered.

Comment: I got it solved.
Just had to set focusable and focusonTouchMode properties of checkbox to false. Thanks Eitherways.

Comment: Please answer your own question and accept it after 2 days. Might help someone else later.

Comment: I did try to. But as I am new, site doesn't allow me too. have to wait till i get enough repo.

Comment: Just edit your question with the solution in it for now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ListView OnItemClickListener Not Responding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367936/listview-onitemclicklistener-not-responding)

Comment: possible duplicate of [List item with CheckBox not clickable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936272/list-item-with-checkbox-not-clickable)

Answer (score 17):

The solution mentioned in the question solves the problem:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

[`AbsListView` checks `View#hasFocusable` and won't allow presses on the item if so. Thus, disable focus on all normally focusable items.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4518810/9636)

Answer (score 6):

Use this line in the rootView of the list item
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

Answer (score 0):

I did misunderstood your issue..**[please have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821871/how-to-fire-onlistitemclick-in-listactivity-with-buttons-in-list)** for your issue.. hope it will resolve your problem..

Comment: I have did the same. Textview,icon and checkbox in one layout.
Mainmenu listview is in another layout.

Comment: Ya i got that..but what i am saying inside your ListItem Layout keep your TextView & Icon in one Layout and set listener on that layout in same way as you did for Checkbox

Comment: i have shared the layouts as an edit. could you show me how..? please?

Comment: I got it solved.
Just had to set focusable and focusonTouchMode properties of checkbox to false.
Thanks eitherways.