# I am using Toast to display on ListViewItem click but toast is not showing up

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter, android-toast

I am using the following code where I want to display some text after ListView Item click. But Toast doesnt appear on click. I have used ArrayList to store the List items

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    linear_top_right = new LinearLayout(this);
    linear_top_right.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    linear_top_left = new LinearLayout(this);
    linear_top_left.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    linear_top = new LinearLayout(this);
    linear_top.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    linear_list = new LinearLayout(this);
    linear_list.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    linear_All = new LinearLayout(this);
    linear_All.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    btn_delete = new Button(this);
    btn_delete.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.select_minus);
    btn_delete.setWidth(15);
    btn_delete.setHeight(15);

    btn_add = new Button(this);
    btn_add.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.select_add);
    btn_add.setWidth(15);
    btn_add.setHeight(15);

    linear_top_right.addView(btn_delete);
    linear_top_right.addView(btn_add);


    chk_select_all = new CheckBox(this);
    chk_src_to_dest = new CheckBox(this);

    chk_select_all.setText("All");
    chk_src_to_dest.setText("SRC to Dest");

    linear_top_left.addView(chk_select_all);
    linear_top_left.addView(chk_src_to_dest);

    listView = new ListView(this);
    linear_list.addView(listView);

    dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.row_create_list,
            allWordList);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    linear_top_right.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    linear_top_right.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

    linear_top_left.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    linear_top.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    linear_list.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    RelativeLayout relative1 = new RelativeLayout(this);
    relative1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    linear_top.addView(linear_top_left);
    linear_top.addView(linear_top_right);
    linear_All.addView(linear_top);
    linear_All.addView(linear_list);
    relative1.addView(linear_All);
    setContentView(relative1);

    final Thread thread = new Thread(){
        @Override
       public void run() {
            try {
               Thread.sleep(5000); // As I am using LENGTH_LONG in Toast
               PracticeTest.this.finish();
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }  
      };
```

//Here I have used listview click

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(PracticeTest.this,"BETA VERSION",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //thread.start();
            WordList list = (WordList) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String listId = list.ListId;
            String listName = list.ListName;
            Intent intent = new Intent(PracticeTest.this,
                    TestListActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Constant.LIST_ID, listId);
            intent.putExtra(Constant.LIST_NAME, listName);

            PracticeTest.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    chk_src_to_dest
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button,
                        boolean checked) {
                    FromSrcToDes = checked;
                }
            });

    chk_select_all
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button,
                        boolean checked) {
                    for (WordList list : allWordList) {
                        list.Ischecked = checked;
                    }
                    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

    btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int itemCount = allWordList.size();
            for (int i = itemCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) // for(WordList list :
                                                        // allWordList)
            {
                WordList list = allWordList.get(i);
                if (list.Ischecked == true) {
                    Util.deleteListId(PracticeTest.this, list.ListId);
                }
            }

            loadAllLists(); // dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //
            chk_select_all.setChecked(false);
        }
    });

    btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(PracticeTest.this,
                    AddWordsToList.class);
            intent.putExtra(Constant.LIST_ID, "");
            PracticeTest.this.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    if (chk_select_all != null)
        chk_select_all.setChecked(false);
    loadAllLists();
}

private void loadAllLists() {
    allWordList.clear();
    String[] listIds = Util.getListIds(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < listIds.length; i++) {
        String listid = listIds[i];
        if (!"".equals(listid)) {
            WordList list = null;
            list = Util.getListData(listid, this);
            if (list != null)
                allWordList.add(list);
        }
    }

    dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.row_create_list,
            allWordList);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            // give test

            WordList list = (WordList) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String listId = list.ListId;
            String listName = list.ListName;
            Intent intent = new Intent(PracticeTest.this,
                    TestListActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Constant.LIST_ID, listId);
            intent.putExtra(Constant.LIST_NAME, listName);
            PracticeTest.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<WordList> {

    private ArrayList<WordList> list;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<WordList> list) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
        this.list = list;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        CheckBox checkBx;
        TextView txt_result;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_create_list, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.checkBx = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            holder.txt_result = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_result);
            holder.checkBx
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button,
                                boolean checked) {

                            list.get(position).Ischecked = checked;
                        }
                    });

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.checkBx.setText(list.get(position).ListName);
        holder.checkBx.setChecked((list.get(position).Ischecked));
        if (list.get(position).TotalWordsAttampted > 0) {
            holder.txt_result.setText("Last attempt "
                    + list.get(position).RightAnswers + "/"
                    + list.get(position).TotalWordsAttampted);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: do you get any error or exception ?

Comment: The code looks alright. Can you post the layout for listview row

Comment: is `onItemClick()` mtethod is called?

Comment: No exception.....it run well but Toast doesnt pop up on screen

Comment: Can you post your full code with xml so it is better to figure out the problem.

Comment: Layout for list is LinearLayout

Comment: try `@Override` on your onItemClick() method

Comment: No I didnt called onItemCLick() explicitly....but everything else is working like intent creation and threads but only Toast is noot showing up

Comment: @kunu doing Override didnt worked

Comment: I have put whole code in question... @Raghunandan

Comment: @user3414076 can you post your xml layout that you inflate in getView?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="checkbox" />
    
@Raghunandan

Comment: <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txt_result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"   
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text=""   
        />

</RelativeLayout> @Raghunandan This is the xml Layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

To the root element in xml

When you click on list item the checkbox takes focus. So add the above to the `RelativeLayout` in xml and re-run the app.

Edit:

Looking closely you already have `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` so the above might not work.

Edit 2:

I tried your code with just strings with same layout

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
 LinearLayout linear_top_right,linear_top_left,linear_top,linear_All,linear_list;
 Button btn_delete,btn_add;
 CheckBox chk_select_all, chk_src_to_dest;
 ListView listView; 
 MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter;
 String allWordList[]= {"A","B","C"};
 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onResume();

     if (chk_select_all != null)
         chk_select_all.setChecked(false);

 }
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    linear_top_right = new LinearLayout(this);
    linear_top_right.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    linear_top_left = new LinearLayout(this);
    linear_top_left.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    linear_top = new LinearLayout(this);
    linear_top.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    linear_list = new LinearLayout(this);
    linear_list.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    linear_All = new LinearLayout(this);
    linear_All.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    btn_delete = new Button(this);

    btn_delete.setWidth(15);
    btn_delete.setHeight(15);

    btn_add = new Button(this);

    btn_add.setWidth(15);
    btn_add.setHeight(15);

    linear_top_right.addView(btn_delete);
    linear_top_right.addView(btn_add);


    chk_select_all = new CheckBox(this);
    chk_src_to_dest = new CheckBox(this);

    chk_select_all.setText("All");
    chk_src_to_dest.setText("SRC to Dest");

    linear_top_left.addView(chk_select_all);
    linear_top_left.addView(chk_src_to_dest);

    listView = new ListView(this);
    linear_list.addView(listView);

    dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.m,
            allWordList);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    linear_top_right.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    linear_top_right.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

    linear_top_left.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    linear_top.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    linear_list.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    RelativeLayout relative1 = new RelativeLayout(this);
    relative1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    linear_top.addView(linear_top_left);
    linear_top.addView(linear_top_right);
    linear_All.addView(linear_top);
    linear_All.addView(linear_list);
    relative1.addView(linear_All);
    setContentView(relative1);

    final Thread thread = new Thread(){
        @Override
       public void run() {
            try {
               Thread.sleep(5000); // As I am using LENGTH_LONG in Toast
               MainActivity.this.finish();
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }  
      };
//Here I have used listview click


    chk_src_to_dest
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button,
                        boolean checked) {

                }
            });

    chk_select_all
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button,
                        boolean checked) {

                }
            });

    btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });

    btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });




    dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.m,
            allWordList);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                   int position, long id) {
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"BETA VERSION",
                          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



           }
       });
}

private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private String[] list;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] allWordList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, allWordList);
        this.list = allWordList;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        CheckBox checkBx;
        TextView txt_result;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.m, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.checkBx = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            holder.txt_result = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_result);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        return convertView;
    }

}
```

m.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="checkbox" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text=" " />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Snap

[image]

Comment: @user3414076 it will. cross check again. You have a checkbox in your layout

Comment: @user3414076 also you have a thread. where do you call start?

Comment: @user3414076 i tired your code with only strings and made the suggestion as posted in my post it works

Answer (score 0):

change the context of the toast to:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"BETA VERSION",
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to the click listerners available in your ListView item (checkbox in this case).

You have to add the below to your Checkboxes (they will work as normal :)),

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859134/listitem-click-doesnt-work-with-checkboxes-android).

Comment: its already there. see his comment `android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:text="checkbox" /> @Raghunandan`

Comment: My bad, missed that. @user3414076 - Try adding the same to the TextView as well.

Comment: Incase this still doesn't work using above and @Raghunandan's answer then there's a workaround but I won't suggest that. Do it only when you find nothing on it. Assign an ID to your RelativeLayout of the ListItem, inflate it in getView as you did for your CheckBox and add the onClick code of ListItem here. (At your own risk ;-))