# onListItemClick on Activity extends ListActivity

Tags: android, listview

I try a listview but when I click on an element I have not my toast

```
public class MarkersListActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String[] titles = new String[] {"Titre 1", "Titre 2", "Titre 3", "Titre 4"};
        String[] des = new String[] {"des 1", "des 2", "des 3", "des 4"};

        setListAdapter( new MarkerListArrayAdapter(this, titles, des));

}

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    //get selected items
    String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

MarkerListArrayAdapter

```
public class MarkerListArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String[] titleText;
private final String[] descriptionText;

public MarkerListArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] titles, String[] description) {
    super(context, R.layout.marker_list_layout, titles);
    this.context = context;
    this.titleText = titles;
    this.descriptionText = description;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.marker_list_layout, parent, false);
    TextView title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView description = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.description);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image);

    title.setText(titleText[position]);
    description.setText(descriptionText[position]);

    imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255,255,0,0));

    return rowView;
}
}
```

The xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/transparent" >
</ImageView>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="30sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: could you post your list item layout file?

Comment: I update my post with all the code

Comment: try to set `layout_width` of the root `LinearLayou` to `fill_parent`

Comment: Thanks, I was not clicking on the text, it works now

Comment: Sometimes there are issues with view focus, check e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316600/android-list-view-clickable-problem

Answer (score 0):

You should use the:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
```

method instead.

Let you `Activity`: `implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`

and then in the `onCreate` add this command:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not called **super** of `onListItemClick()`...
Do as follows:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){ 
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary. `onListItemClick` is empty by default.

Comment: I always have the same problem adding super

Answer (score 0):

You have to set setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) method in MarkersListActivity class and your listview **ID** should be "@android:id/list"

Add this layout **activity_main**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingLeft="8dp"
     android:paddingRight="8dp">

 <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" //Important this one.
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="#00FF00"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Have a look at the official documentation for listactivity
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html